# Is there any way to add a regular ARAnchor on a detected image?

Tags: objective-c, arkit

I'm trying to put a 3D object on top of the detected image, and it worked. But when I moved the camera around the image, the object didn't stay at the center of image. Is there any way to add a regular anchor at the center of image to help me fix the 3D object at the right position? The following code is what I've tried, but it not worked.

```py
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor 
{
    if ([anchor isKindOfClass:[ARImageAnchor class]]) {
        ARAnchor *newAnchor = [[ARAnchor alloc] initWithTransform:anchor.transform];
        [self.sceneView.session addAnchor:newAnchor];
    }
}
```

[I detect an image and put a plane on it, it looks center correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dcqx.png)

[But when I move the camera to another position, it doesn't locate on the center of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgL88.png)

Comment: How do you handle and make the node related to the anchor, in renderer `nodeFor` delegate?

Comment: No, I handle it in ```renderer didAdd forAnchor``` delegate

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a new anchor because there's already one provided by ARKit. You should add your 3D content to the node provided by this method.
According to the `renderer:didAddNode:forAnchor:` documentation:

> You can provide visual content for the anchor by attaching geometry (or other SceneKit features) to this node or by adding child nodes.

So, in this method:

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor 
{
     [node addChildNode: your3DObjectNode];
}
```

Then it should stay at the center of your image.

Comment: The object stay at center of the image when added, but when I move the camera around the object, it did not look like center on image.

Comment: It sounds like an issue in the 3D model then. Perhaps it is not centered correctly? Open the model in a 3D editor and see if it is aligned correctly. Otherwise, posting an image or video of your issue will help me to understand your issue better.